# Notification Icon in .NET MAUI Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

I'm facing an issue with push notifications in .NET MAUI. I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging and I have successfully integrated it into my app. The problem is with the notification icon; when I receive a notification while using the app, the icon is displayed correctly, but if I receive the notification when the app is closed, the icon appears small and inside a larger circle (which doesn't look good). I've tried using both SVG and PNG files with colored or white and transparent backgrounds, but nothing seems to work. That's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9m3g.png) I have used.

Here are the screenshots of the problem:

Inside the app:
[image: Inside the app]

And if I scroll down while in the app:
[image: And if I scroll down while in the app]

Outside the app (when closed):
[image: Outside the app (when closed)]

And again, if I scroll down while the app is closed:
[image: And again, if I scroll down while the app is closed]

These examples were made using a PNG file named *small_notification_icon.png* and saved in the *Resources/Images* folder, which only uses white color with a transparent background. This is the code I used:

```
var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.ChannelID)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.small_notification_icon)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetChannelId(MainActivity.ChannelID)
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);

var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NotificationID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you please share the image you used (`small_notification_icon.png`) here so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have updated the post with the requested information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've identified the issue. When the app runs in the background, notifications sent from the console use the launcher icon designated in the manifest file.

To address the problem, you can simply replace the default image specified in the `AndroidManifest` by inserting the following code within the `Application` tag. All you need to do is substitute your_favourite_image with the image you prefer for the notification icon.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/your_favourite_image" />
```

This should resolve the issue and allow you to use your preferred image for notifications.

Comment: And where do you post the image in MAUI ? in image ? or you create a folder with the name drawable in resources ? and in witch format ? thanks

Comment: @justcivah, i have put my appiconfg.svg into Resources/Images, but i get "resource drawable/appiconfg not found" error on compilation...

Comment: @MikeTsayper The default icon name in a .NET MAUI project is `appicon`. If you change that name you also have to rename the `android:icon` and `android:iconRound` property in the `AndroidManifest`. In your case you want: `android:icon="@mipmap/appiconfg" and android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appiconfg_round"`. Hope it helps!

Comment: @sly You can save the image in the `Images` folder. It should work both with png and svg extension, but I only tried with svg.

Answer (score 0):

I used `.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.appiconfg)` and it is fine. It uses my app icon, which is an SVG file in the project.

Comment: This is inside the /Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs

Comment: Also, this does not set the app icon for when it is closed. It does set the app icon when it's open.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy resolution:**

1. replace the image in Resources > Images > dotnet_bot.svg
2. Now, use the smalliconref dotnet_bot `FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.SmallIconRef = Resource.Drawable.dotnet_bot`
3. Example:

```
    private void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            var channelId = $"{PackageName}.general";
            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "General", NotificationImportance.High);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.ChannelId = channelId;
            FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.SmallIconRef = Resource.Drawable.dotnet_bot;
        }
```